# R language Loop If statements

Tags: r

I have a dataset of 6 column and 4.5 millions rows. I would like to write a logical check if in the fifth column there are values with zeroes, to put 1 in the sixth column. Could you explain me how to construct an algorithm to do this? In the fifth column I found that I have cells with zero value. I want to perform if in the fifth column I have zero values to put 1 in sixth column and if not to put 0?

Comment: try `library(data.table);setDT(df1)[!V5, V6:=1]`

Comment: The algorithm is in the sentences you just wrote. :)

Comment: @akrun, not every user is worried about a few microseconds more or less

Comment: @akrun, btw, using your sample data, `system.time(df3[,6] <- as.integer(df3[,5] == 0))` is faster than `system.time(setDT(df2)[, V6:= (!V5)+0L])` on my laptop. Sure, if you increase the sample data to some GB, your solution will possibly scale better but the answer with upvotes is not generally slow.

Comment: @akrun, if you look at the edited question, the last sentence makes it clear what they are looking for (it was indeed unclear in the original question)

Comment: @akrun, I got: `system.time(setDT(df2)[, V6:= (!V5)+0L]) # 0.059       0.006       0.064` and `system.time(df3[,6] <- as.integer(df3[,5] == 0)) # 0.047       0.011       0.057 `. My point is that those approaches are very similar in speed and there's no need to worry about the microsecond-differences in most use cases

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80558/discussion-between-docendo-discimus-and-akrun).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ifelse function :

```
df[,6] = ifelse(df[,5] == 0, 1, df[,6])
```

Or without ifelse:

```
df[,6] <- as.integer(df[,5] == 0)
```

where df is your data.frame.

The second approach will put 0's into column 6 whenever column 5 is not 0 and 1s otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 setDT(df1)[(!V5), V6:=1]
```

If you need binary values for 'V6' based on 'V5'

```
 setDT(df1)[, V6:= as.integer(!V5)]
```

#### Benchmarks

```
 set.seed(246)
 df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:5, 6*1e7, replace=TRUE), ncol=6))
 df3 <- copy(df2)
 df4 <- copy(df2)

system.time(df2[,6] <- ifelse(df2[,5] == 0, 1, df2[,6]))
# user  system elapsed 
#  1.455   0.146   1.604 


system.time(`<-`(df3[,6][!df3[,5]],1))
# user  system elapsed 
 # 0.085   0.022   0.108 

system.time(setDT(df4)[(!V5), V6:=1])
 #user  system elapsed 
 # 0.054   0.007   0.060
```

#### EDIT

After the edit, it seems like the second option is what the OP needed.  The timings are

```
system.time(df3[,6] <- as.integer(df3[,5] == 0))
 #  user  system elapsed 
 # 0.099   0.008   0.110 
system.time(setDT(df2)[, V6:= (!V5)+0L])
#   user  system elapsed 
# 0.039   0.005   0.047 

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(akrun=setDT(df2)[, V6:= (!V5)+0L],
  fmarm= df3[,6] <- as.integer(df3[,5]==0), unit='relative', times=20L)
#Unit: relative
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq    max neval cld
# akrun 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.0000    20  a 
# fmarm 2.546095 2.525371 2.490122 2.516731 2.411705 2.4011    20   b
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(384)
 df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:5, 6*20, replace=TRUE), ncol=6))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
`<-`(df[,6][!df[,5]],1)
```

Comment: I don't find this very readable tbh and therefore not a particurlarly good recommendation for a (possibly) new R user (not saying it's wrong)

Comment: I don't understand your point.

Comment: I reverted the index 5 and 6 , it's corrected!

Comment: df is my data frame right?

Comment: this is entirely correct!

Comment: Thank you very much for help. I have completed my aim. I really appreciate your support. :)

Comment: How to count them if i use data.table?